# How to open a text file in QT creator using either QFile or fstream

Tags: c++, qt, text-files, fstream, qfile

```
QFile file("D:/QT/employee manager ui/EmployeeManager/‪employeeLogIn.txt");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "info", file.errorString());
}
```

I tried to use fstream, and ifstream to open the the file in QT creator, but I could not open the file. I used both back slash and double forward slash while specifying the file location. Last night, my code ran, but doesn't open the file.

This project has qmake build system, and QT widget application

thank you!

Comment: Does the file actually exist? Is it readable by the user who's running your executable?

Comment: Try to use double backslashes

Comment: Ensure file exists and the provided path text complies the letter case.  Code sample from documentation `QFileInfo info1("C:\\Users\\Bob\\untabify.lnk");`

Comment: So... why don't you tell us what the error message box says? Btw. you should use either one forward slash (everywhere) or two backward slash (only on Windows).

Comment: @V.K. author of HiFile the error message I got from the if statement is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: @Alexey I tried that, but didn't work.

QFile file("D:\\QT\\updated\\employee manager ui\\EmployeeManager\\employeeLogIn.lnk");

Comment: @paolo Yes, I created a txt file, entered information, and saved it in the same folder as cpp file. Iremember working with files last week ( https://youtu.be/XEAqgcoSlk4?t=4252 ), but this week, its not working.

Comment: Are you trying to open a `.txt` or a `.lnk` file?

Comment: @paolo I am trying to open .txt file, 

I dont know much about .ink file